# Redirect logs to logstash instance instead of ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have a question :

I`m using Elasticsearch.Net nugget with NLogs in order to send logs to my local Elasticsearch instance. Kibana is visualize them as well, so far soo good.

Is it possible using the same nugget to forwards logs to Logstash instance which is expose on my production environment instead to ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334258/1831), you could use NLog to write logs to a local directory, then use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) to ship those logs to [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

Comment: Is it possible to make your suggestion work if the application is put in Docker container ?

Comment: That's a different question :) Take a look at Docker's logging drivers for options for how to ship logs out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The `Elasticsearch.Net` client can not directly write to logstash instances.